# how to "grep" text in the middle with special chars

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep

```
Unexpected header.nextMessage.response.statusLine.statusCode := 403 with 180 unmatched
```

I want to grep the following text into var: `nextMessage.response.statusLine.statusCode := 403`

I used this command: `exp=$(grep -oP '(?<=header).+(?=with)' text.txt)` but it fetched only this part:`.nextMessage.response.statusLine.statusCode` without 403.

Comment: `echo "Unexpected header.nextMessage.response.statusLine.statusCode := 403 with 180 unmatched" | grep -oP '(?<=header).+(?=with)'` works for me with gnu grep 2.16. What version of grep do you use?

Comment: grep (GNU grep) 2.10. But I can't update it cuz I work in specific environment where I haven't access to update anything.
emm....I checked: with "echo" it works

Comment: maybe it could be the problem that actually I use 2 grep in pipe:
exp=($(grep "*with*" text.txt | grep -oP '(?<=header).+(?=with)' text.txt))

Comment: Can you change your regex to something like `grep -oP '(?<=header).+:= \d+` ? (You have filtered for `with` in the first grep).

Comment: I found a box where I have GNU grep  2.10 installed and it works like this for me:
 
`$ echo "$x" | grep -oP "(?<=er\.).+(?=with)" `                     
outputs: `nextMessage.response.statusLine.statusCode := 403`

Comment: I also tested the same way that you are via a file single quotes, etc just for consistency and I can't replicate it. I would try setting the one line in your example to a variable and testing the grep. I am willing to bet it will work. My next query would be what encoding is the `text.txt` file.

Comment: How about `echo "Unexpected header.nextMessage.response.statusLine.statusCode := 403 with 180 unmatched" | sed 's/.*\(header.next.*\) with.*/\1/'` ?

Comment: Explain the criteria you need to use to find your matching striung and include a few more lines of input that you do NOT want to match and the output for all of it. `var="nextMessage.response.statusLine.statusCode := 403"` is a valid solution to your problem as described so far.

Answer (score 2):

It **sounds** like you're just using the wrong tool and all you need is:

```
$ var=$(sed 's/.*header\.\(.*\) with.*/\1/' file)
$ echo "$var"
nextMessage.response.statusLine.statusCode := 403
```

but it's hard to tell from your question as currently written.

When trying to figure out which UNIX tool to use to manipulate text, remember these guidelines:

grep = `g/re/p` = the `ed` commands to **G**lobally search for a **R**egular **E**xpression and **P**rint the resulting string. Its is not a tool to edit text.

sed = **S**tream **ED**itor = to perform simple substitutions on individual lines. Used to have to do more and still has a ton of bizarre language constructs to let it, but everything other than s, g, and p (with -n) became obsolete in the mid-1970s when awk was invented.

awk = the general purpose text manipulation tool that comes as standard with sed and grep on all UNIX installations. Use it for anything that doesn't fit into the grep or sed categories.

Comment: thanks for your user guide:) but in my case I don't actually know which tool I should use to fulfill my requirements. In genaral I have such content in the log file:
`@@COMP3,INVITE_E (4),INVITE_E (4),pass 
 @#COMP3,Unexpected header in 403,,,fail \n
 Unexpected header.nextMessage.response.statusLine.statusCode := 403 with 180 unmatched
 @#COMP4,Unexpected header in BYE_E (1),,,fail \n
 Unexpected header BYE_E (1) with INVITE_E (4) unmatched`

and what I need is: take some values from the line without @# chars and put them on specific place into line above between commas.

Comment: Refer to the guide I provided again and you'll find it tells you which tool to use. You want to take parts of one line and insert them into another line. That is NOT just looking for a regexp and printing the result so it's not a job for grep. That is also NOT a simple substitution on an individual line since it operates across 2 lines so it's not a job for sed. Therefore it's a job for awk. If you post a new question with concise, testable, realistic sample input and expected output we can show you how to do the job the right way.

Comment: thanks for info. I will try it on my own first of all :)

Comment: Sounds good but make sure you try it with awk only, not some mush of shell/grep/sed/whatever as doing it with the latter would be like wanting to boil water and so building a campfire in your kitchen next to the oven to do so instead of just turning the oven on. Sure you can achieve the goal but .....

Comment: I have done it, "grepping" necessary lines into new file and set in proper place with awk. Thanks, Ed ! ))

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
exp=$(grep -oP '(?=nextMessage).+(?=with)' text.txt)
```

or

```
exp=$(cat text.txt | grep -oP '(?=nextMessage).+(?=with)')
```

both worked for me.

Comment: your regex is invalid... unless you know something I don't: `(^header)` is not the start of the line.

Comment: also did you take into consideration the previous comments on the question. If you did you would know this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: I see what your saying, I was focused on getting the 403 added.